# Autocomplete jQuery Change is not triggered until the user clicks outside the input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm having an issue with jQuery Autocomplete. I am trying to retrieve the value that user selects from autocomplete list with

```
$( ".autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  change: function( event, ui ) {
      var SelectedValue = $(#autocomplete).val();
    }
});
```

However, this is not being called until the user clicks outside the autocomplete input field. I need to trigger this right after the user selects an item from the list and the item appears in the autocomplete input field.

The code that I have:

```
<div>
 <input id="autocomplete" type="text" />
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
$( function() {

$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: "items.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            term: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
          response( data );
          }
        } );
      },
      minLength: 1,
      select: function( event, ui ) {

        $("#autocomplete").val(ui.item.value);
    },

 } );

});
```

I tried the following but it didn't fix it. 
`$("#autocomplete").val(ui.item.value).trigger('change')`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to trap the `select` event like so:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var SelectedValue = ui.item.value;
    }
});
```

There is no need to do `$("#autocomplete").val(ui.item.value)`... the select event handler does it for you.